# how do i run my tsup javascript bundle on browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundler

I'm using [Tsup](https://github.com/egoist/tsup) to create a small library using typescript + React. The problem is how can i set up my environment to see the changes on my browser while I develop?

I have created a dummy structure to run javascript bundle on my browser as,

```
dist
  index.js
  index.mjs
src
  index.html
  App.tsx
  index.tsx
tsup.config.ts
tsconfig.json
```

My `index.html`. files is quite simple, that attaches a `dist/index.js` as a script (this script is a bundle generated by tsup)

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../dist/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.tsx

```
import React from "react"
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client"
import App from "./App"

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!)
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

App.tsx

```
import React from "react"

interface Props {}

function App(props: Props) {
  const {} = props

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I have a very simple tsconfig file as follows :

```
import { defineConfig } from "tsup"

export default defineConfig({
  minify: true,
  target: "es2015",
  external: ["react"],
  sourcemap: true,
  dts: true,
  format: ["esm", "cjs"],
  injectStyle: true,
  esbuildOptions(options) {
    options.banner = {
      js: '"use client"',
    }
  },
})
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And, I'm using terminal(using package.json script) to generate javascript bundle using tsup as

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsup src/index.tsx",
    "dev": "tsup src/index.tsx --watch",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
```

Finally, I have tried live-server to run this `index.html` file in the browser, but it doesn't work at all.

I get the following error in my browser console :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index.tsx:1:19
```

Any idea whats the issue here? I initially thought maybe the `type="module"` in the script tag(in index.html file) would fix this, but it does not. If anyone can help me out.

Comment: Remove `external: ["react"]` so that the react code is bundled in the final output. And then, also set the `format` to `umd`. Browsers only understand `umd` unless you decide to use module scripts.

Comment: As an alternative, why not use something like vite to make a dev setup for you. It comes with HMR and a lot of other QoL things. It's a good tool to be familiar with.

Comment: @vighnesh153 so umd is not supported in tsup i think, so i included "iife" . It created a `index.global.js` file. But now, the error on the browser is - `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at index.js:3:5
    at index.global.js:2:229
    at index.tsx:1:19
    at index.tsx:10:1`

Comment: i'm taking inspiration from sonner - `https://github.com/emilkowalski/sonner` @vighnesh153

Comment: Yea sorry it is called iffe in tsup

Comment: Is `process` being used to read the environment? Like `process.env.NODE_ENV`? If yes, we might have to provide a substitution for that in the tsup config.

Comment: For using it in browser, you will have to bundle `react` directly in the output. Or, you can bundle it without `react` but then at the place you are using it, you will have to include `react`.

Comment: `sonner` is a good reference. You can follow that. You will have to create a different website package to consume the library.

Comment: @vighnesh153 what do you mean by "For using it in browser, you will have to bundle react directly in the output. Or, you can bundle it without react"

Comment: I say this not to offend: we all started somewhere and you may well have a very bright future ahead of you. But if you don't already know the answer to this problem/can't solve it by googling on your own, you aren't (yet) qualified to write libraries for other people to use.

Comment: @JaredSmith Sorry my good sir, I did not know we have people here from qualification department.

Comment: What I meant was that if you are using this on a browser directly, you will need to bundle `react`. But for publishing as a library, don't bundle it (set external: ['react']). For doing this, you can define 2 different configs: `defineConfig([{...}, {...}])`, one for your dev website and one for your library.

Answer (score 2):

After doing trial and error, i finally ran this by changing my configuration as:

```
import { defineConfig } from "tsup"

export default defineConfig({
  minify: true,
  target: "es2015",
  // external: ["react"],
  sourcemap: true,
  dts: true,
  format: ["esm", "cjs", "iife"],
  injectStyle: true,
  esbuildOptions(options) {
    options.define = {
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production"),
    }
    options.banner = {
      js: '"use client"',
    }
  },
})
```